# GoogleApiClient is not connected yet exception

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

The application i'm working on, works properly sometimes but some other times it gives me this error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.dell.locationapi/com.example.dell.locationapi.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.

And sometimes this error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.

even though the `onConnected()` function is called.
I moved the calling of `buildGoogleApiClient()`  to the begining of`onCreate()` here is my code:

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
 }
```

calling the methods in `onCreate()`:

```
    loc = new MyLocation(MainActivity.this);
    if (loc.checkPlayServices()) {
        loc.buildGoogleApiClient();
        loc.createLocationRequest();
    }
```

but it keeps giving the same error sometimes, any idea why this happens?!

Comment: Could you manage to pass this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `loc.createLocationRequest();` immediate after you call `loc.buildGoogleApiClient();` Instead you call  `loc.createLocationRequest()` in `onConected()` of ApiCLient. `loc.createLocationRequest()` requires the GoogleApiClient to be connected by the time it is called.

For that matter, you should call any API that needs APiCLient connected in `onConnected()`. This way you avoid ApiClient connect exceptions while you use them.

Comment: A down vote, good. I would like to hear you what was wrong in the answer so I can correct it and even people would why..otherwise it mislead. If you can not take your vote.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming late but for whoever it might be useful for:

1. Move `loc.buildGoogleApiClient();` to the onCreate method.
2. Move `loc.createLocationRequest();` to the onConnected method.