# Android:GoogleApiClient is not connected yet?

Tags: android, location, google-api-client

To update a user's current location 
I implement the following method to my project:

GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

When the project is executed,The following error will occur:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

And there is an error in the code:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

Many solutions have been proposed,Like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891324/googleapiclient-is-not-connected-yet-exception) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343922/googleapiclient-is-throwing-googleapiclient-is-not-connected-yet-after-onconne)
But not solve any problem.

Please Help To Solve It.

My Code In onCreate Method:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("Exceptin"));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(60*1000) 
                .setFastestInterval(1*1000);}
```

And in onMapReady:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);}
```

And This:

```
   protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

 @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

 if (servicesAvailable()) {
            // Get best last location measurement meeting criteria
            mLastLocation = bestLastKnownLocation(MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY, FIVE_MIN);

            if (null == mLastLocation
                    || mLastLocation.getAccuracy() > MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY
                    || mLastLocation.getTime() < System.currentTimeMillis() - TWO_MIN) {

                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

                // Schedule a runnable to unregister location listeners
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, MainActivity.this);//This Line Return Error
                    }

                }, ONE_MIN, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
        }else{
            handleNewLocation(mLastLocation);
        }

    }
```

Thank You For Any Help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem because I use splash screen in my project  put this code in splash screen activity :

```
    mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the full implementation that works for me..

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    LocationListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection established. Fetching location ..");
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.d("Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + "Lng : " + location.getLongitude());    
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }

    public synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

            @Override
        public void onStart(){
            super.onStart();
            if(this.googleApiClient != null){
                    this.googleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly but the problem is not resolved.

Comment: is the exception still occur?

Comment: you have to create `mGoogleClient` in oncreate() first

Comment: yes mGoogleClient  is in onCreate() but nullexception occur in onStart()...

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate you are calling `getMapAsync()` without a client.

You need to call `mGoogleClient.connect()` in `onCreate` , then move your `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)` to `onConnected`.